# Intellij 2022.2.3 : Indent Java Lambok and Stream Code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, indentation

```
    TestDTO.builder().date(Date.from(Instant.now())).productName("product " + i).total(new BigDecimal(i)).purchaseType(1).sourceAppId("sourceAppId" + i).numberOfLicense(i).build();
List.of("a", "bb", "cccc").stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).filter(s -> s.length() > 1).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Above is my Java in which am trying to indent it to have each method in a new line as below, I'm wondering if this is doable with IntelliJ Java code format config changes or not? I tried ctrl+shift+L and its not doing what I expected

```
TestDTO.builder()
          .date(Date.from(Instant.now()))
          .productName("product " + i)
          .total(new BigDecimal(i)).purchaseType(1)
          .sourceAppId("sourceAppId" + i)
          .numberOfLicense(i)
          .build();
List.of("a", "bb", "cccc").stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(s -> s.length() > 1)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You can refer to this spec https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-style-java.html#wrapping_and_braces_tab and check options in 'Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces', especially "Chained method calls"

Answer (score 1):

From the comments: You can setup this behaviour in the IntelliJ-settings.
It is under `Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java` in the tab `Wrapping and braces` and it is called `Chained method calls`.

But be aware: Sometimes you might dislike this. In your example, you want that `List.of("a", "bb", "cccc").stream()` is in one line. But it is a chained method call and IntelliJ do this:

```java
List.of("a", "bb", "cccc")
    .stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .filter(s -> s.length() > 1)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If want you that setting, then it is properly a good idea to put it into a [EditorConfig](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/editorconfig.html).

#### .editorconfig

```
[*.java]
ij_java_method_call_chain_wrap = always
```